# Get Success Results From AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the results from an AJAX call, but I keep getting the error results of the function and I have no idea why.

Here is the javascript:

```
var curfrndurl = "http://www.website.com/app/curfrnd.php?frndid=" + secondLevelLocation + "&userid=" + items; 

$("#loadpage1").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: curfrndurl,
dataType: 'json',
type: "GET",
success: function (data){
    if (data.success) {

     alert("Hi");
     $("#curstatus").html(data);
     $("#curstatus2").hide();
     $("#subtform").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Bye");
        $("#curstatus2").html(data);
        $("#curstatus").hide();
        $("#addform").hide();
    }
},
error: function() {

alert('Doh!');
 }
});
});
```

The PHP file is:

```
<?php 
$userdbme = $_GET['userid'];
$frndid = $_GET['frndid'];

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE yoozer1='$userdbme' AND yoozer2='$frndid' ORDER BY followid DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$numfriends = mysql_num_rows($query2);
if ($numfriends!=0)
{


 echo json_encode(array(
'success' => true
//'user_name' => $userdb
));
echo "<h4>Current Friends</h4>";
}
else {

echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
echo "<h4>Not Friends</h4>";
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Ensure the URL is correct. Also, log the contents of `data` (where it returns successful or not) and update your question with its contents. You've not provided enough information to debug this issue.

Comment: Instead of `alert('Doh!');`, you should print out the *message* given to you from the error function.  `error(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }`

Comment: P.S. Is your code on the same domain as the URL?  Or does that URL use CORS/JSONP?

Comment: `<h4>Current Friends</h4>` is not JSON.  You *cannot* echo anything else *after* `json_encode()` if you want to echo JSON.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! That was it. Thanks Rocket!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to echo JSON data, then you need to make sure you don't echo anything else before or after the data.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true
));
echo "<h4>Current Friends</h4>";
```

This is not parsable as JSON, because of the "extra" stuff after the JSON data.  Try this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'html' => "<h4>Current Friends</h4>"
));
```

Then you can do: `$("#curstatus").html(data.html);`